# Openlayers marker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openlayers

is there a way to click marker created by OpenLayers.Marker() to be able to redirect to another link.

i have tried

```
var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(position, icon.clone());

marker.events.register("click", map, function(e) {
   location.href = "http:www.google.com"
});
```

by doing so, i am able to have a click event when i click the marker and redirects me to www.google.com. But what i am interested to know is, am i able to set the url directly to the marker when i create the marker in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add any property to your marker like this:

```
marker.URL = "http://www.google.com/";
```

Then your event handler can be written once like this:

```
function linkHandler(e) {
    location.href = this.URL;
}

marker.events.register("click", marker, linkHandler);
```

Note that the "map" parameter in the marker.events.register call was changed to "marker".